# How to quit ZXing's scanning mode when Back button is pressed

Tags: android, zxing

I have a simple QR code scanning app. Here's the flowchart which describes its logic.
[image]

And this is the main part:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

public class ScanActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(ScanActivity.this);
        scanIntegrator.setOrientationLocked(false);
        scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (scanResult != null){
            String strResult = scanResult.getContents();
            Intent iii = new Intent(ScanActivity.this, ScanResultActivity.class);
            iii.putExtra("scan_result", strResult);
            startActivity(iii);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
}
```

If you are in ScanActivity, then the app will immediately display ScanResultActivity after scanning, which is as expected. The only issue is app won't quit when Back key is pressed. Instead, it will jump to ScanResultActivity. Of course, the scanning result is null.

How to quit the app by pressing Back key when scanning is running?

Full code: https://github.com/anta40/QRScanDemo

Answer (score 0):

this method

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

should call the super method, like this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Just tried that. It won't close your app. From ScanActivity, it'll jump automatically to ScanResultActivity.